# Remove bad character "\xC2" python string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex, character

I have the next code:

```
string_msg = '\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x53\x58\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\x74\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x54\x00\x00\x00\x03'
print(string_msg)
if sys.version < '3':
    print(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in string_msg))
else:
    print(":".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in string_msg.encode()))
```

In python 2, the result is:

```
80:01:00:00:00:00:53:58:00:1c:00:00:00:08:00:01:00:74:00:00:00:0a:00:54:00:00:00:03
```

But in python 3, the result is:

```
c2:80:01:00:00:00:00:53:58:00:1c:00:00:00:08:00:01:00:74:00:00:00:0a:00:54:00:00:00:03
```

Right now I need to execute this code in python 3 so I have to remove the first byte at the beginning in order to remove the "c2" and everything would be OK, but trying to do that with too many pieces of code I found in this forum such as:

```
string_msg = string_msg[1:]
string_msg.replace('\xC2', '')
string_msg = ''.join([i if ord(i) < 130 else '' for i in string_msg])
```

The result is always the same:

```
01:00:00:00:00:53:58:00:1c:00:00:00:08:00:01:00:74:00:00:00:0a:00:54:00:00:00:03
```

Removing also the second byte `80`, so my question is: How can I remove just the first byte `c2` and why when I try to do that the second byte is also removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `string_msg` is a bytestring on Python 2 and despite looking the same it is a Unicode string on Python 3 -- a byte `b'\x80'` is a completely different concept from a Unicode codepoint `u'\x80'`: the same Unicode codepoint can be represented using different bytes in different encodings and vice versa the same byte may represent different characters in different encodings.

If `string_msg` is a sequence of bytes then use `b''` literal:

```
data = b'\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x53\x58\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x08'
print(":".join(map("{:02x}".format, bytearray(data))))
# -> 80:01:00:00:00:00:53:58:00:1c:00:00:00:08
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem. I didn't know this little difference between python2 and python3. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert text in the first 256 characters to its naive byte value by encoding as ISO 8859-1.

```
3>> '\x80'.encode('latin-1')
b'\x80'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally the problem was solved applying the solution suggested by @J.F.Sebastian. Concretely, python2 and python3 manage the same variable as different things (the first one as a Unicode and the second one as a byte).